How read xlsx file starting on a certain line as a readable payload in mule 4 using anypoint studio?
I have an xlsx file that I need to read the file starting on line A15 into a readable payload in mule 4 using anypoint studio. The file resides in a repo location inside of aws S3 so i'm using the aws s3 connector (Get Object) to read the file. Once the xlsx file is read by the Get Object connector the payload looks like this :
"PK\u0001\u0002\u0015\u0000\u0002\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000\uddddP\"\ufffd\f\u0003\u0000\u0000\ufffd\u001e\u0000\u0000\u0043\u0000\b\u0002[Content_Types].xml \ufffd\u0001\u0002(\ufffd"

I have a transform that will convert the above payload into a readable json output like:
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import remove from dw::core::Strings
import last,first from dw::core::Strings

var xlsx = readUrl(payload, "application/xlsx")
var data = xlsx."Member Detail" map (key,value)->{
    name : if (isEmpty(key.A) or key.A == null) '' else key.A first 500,
    id : if (isEmpty(key.C) or key.C == null) '' else key.C first 250,
        address: if (isEmpty(key.B) or key.B == null) '' else key.B first 250
}

For all of my xlsx files, the file headers start on line 15 so the data reads successfully. However, sometimes the files are formatted poorly when a Data Through and a Date is added above the header on line 11. This causes the data in column A and B to get messy and tricky to map. Basically i need a way for the xlsx file to read the headers on line 15 only. See image example: xlsx example where data is added above the header line
I attempted to add MIME Type application/xlsx with a parameter of tableOffset = A15 on the aws Get Object connector that read the xlsx file. I also tried to add MIME Type application/xlsx with a parameter of tableOffset = A15 to a Set Payload. MIME Type tableOffset example Neither of these approaches worked to read the payload beginning on line A15. The payload still looked like the below:
"PK\u0001\u0002\u0015\u0000\u0002\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u0000\uddddP\"\ufffd\f\u0003\u0000\u0000\ufffd\u001e\u0000\u0000\u0043\u0000\b\u0002[Content_Types].xml \ufffd\u0001\u0002(\ufffd"

My expectation was something readable.

What is the full script? You are only sharing the header with no script body. For the flow please don't use screenshots. Reserve those for non textual data. copy the XML of that component into the question. What do you mean it doesn't work? Provide an example of the actual output and expected output. Please read How to Ask to improve your question.

Why are you using readUrl() using the payload as an URL? Were you trying to use read() instead? That would not make sense either since the payload already it an XLS file.
